# Can I redistribute MailKit.dll and MimeKit.dll with my PowerShell Script?

Tags: mailkit

Can I redistribute only MailKit.dll and MimeKit.dll that are included in package(installer)?

I know the MailKit is under the MIT License but I don't understand whether I can redistribute only the dlls.

I write a PowerShell Script that uses the MailKit.dll and MimeKit.dll and I want to distribute them as a package. Is it OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can redistribute the dll's.